# Clariion CX300: Removing system disks from a RAID group?

Tags: raid, storage-area-network, emc, lun, clariion

I have a raid group that includes every disk my DPE2.

I want to remove the system disks (0-4) from this RAID group.

From what I read I should i put them in their own RAID group and avoid storing user data on them if possible.

Will destroying this RAID group blow out the data on these disc? Would that mean I'd have to re-install FLARE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer from EMC forums:](https://community.emc.com/thread/183738)

"
Short answer - no.  The FLARE OS code resides on a Private area reserved on the Vault drives.  You can provision space from the Vault drives, but not the OS area.  You can remove LUNs provisioned from the User area on the Vault drives without destroying the FLARE OS region.

The Private area on the disks is a series of small LUNs that are not exposed to the user provisioning tools.  Basically, when you add a Vault disk to a RAID Group, the CX "ignores" the private area on the Vault.  Think of it like LVM, which allows you to add logical partitions (LUNs on physical disks) to build up larger logical partitions for filesystems.
"

Comment: If your raid includes these first four drives but has other ones as well, it's possible that there is a stripe of wasted space on all the other drives. On normal traditional raid groups, each disk has to have the same capacity, and when they don't, the controller will only the capacity of the smallest member on all the other members.